# Only print specific information to String

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase app where I am able to use a datasnapshot to return a users UID and Score from my Firebase realtime database.

When I run this code:

```js
package com.example.securityapp;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import static java.lang.System.in;

public class leaderboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseUsers;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    TextView score;
    private static final String TAG = "leaderboard";
    String s;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tableText);

        leaderBoard();




    }

    public void leaderBoard(){
        database.getReference().child("Scores").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    System.out.println("The score is: " + snapshot.toString());
                    s = s + snapshot.toString() + "\n";
                    score.setText(s);
                }



            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

            }


        });

    }


}
```

I get this as a result:
[image]

Is there anyway to only have the key value and points value returned as opposed to all of the other information that comes along with it?

The current state of the leaderboard screen:
[image]

```js
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".leaderboard">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.38">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="420dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Leaderboard!"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#0C40F1"
                android:textSize="50dp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="User ID"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:text="Points"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textSize="20dp"/>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tableText"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

Thanks

Comment: What other information? I only see key and value in your dataSnapshot object.

Comment: have you tried to override the toString method on DataSnapshot?

Comment: Instead of having DataSnapshot { key = KBEZRw&GDgTsWCm6Ghhv8A0YkV2, value = {Points=1} } I would like the screen to just have KBEZRw&GDgTsWCm6Ghhv8A0YkV2 and 1 shown. I am trying to make a table leaderboard but have only managed to make a table with headings and can only display the data as one big string in a row of the table. Ive updated my question to show what happens when I run the activity.

Comment: Hey @Jocke I havent. How would I do that? Sorry Im very new to programming

Answer (score 1):

You're loading the entire `Scores` node, but apparently only want to show the value of a single property of each child. In that case you can look up the value of that property with something like:

```
database.getReference().child("Scores").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println("The score is: " + snapshot.child("Points").getValue());
            s = s + snapshot.toString() + "\n";
            score.setText(s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

Comment: I need the screen to show as a table where the UID and Points are shown but at the minute `DataSnapshot { key = KBEZRw&GDgTsWCm6Ghhv8A0YkV2, value = {Points=1} } ` shows on screen instead of just `KBEZRw&GDgTsWCm6Ghhv8A0YkV2, 1`

Comment: Check the change in my code, and it will *only* log the value of points to `System.out`. To get the key, you'd do `snapshot.getKey()`. So to combine both in `score`, you need `s = s + snapshot.getkey() + ", " + snapshot.child("Points").getValue()`

Comment: Thank you so much, do you know if theres anyway of removing the null from the first result? I understand that its there because of the loop, but is there anyway to get rid of it?